# C++ Bit Operations: How to decode / decompress char to int, and display correct string?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, decode, compression

I'm studying bit operations. Starting at the 8th iteration of my decode/decompress algorithm, my bits begin to drift in and out of control, and I need some help from a more experienced/smarter person, so my bits don't drift. I've been through it in my debugger too many times to count and I still can't nail it down. I suspect that at some point I shift a bit left or right too far by 1 or more. Full program is on Github [here](https://github.com/NonCreature0714/Bit_Operations).

Input to decode/decompress is:

```
unsigned char bytes[25] = { 9,0,207,176,159,163,255,33,58,115,
                              199,255,255,181,223,67,102,69,173,
                              6,35,103,245,160,164 };
```

Reference array is:

```
const char symbols[27] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
                          'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
                          'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' '};
```

Output from the decoded 'bytes' char array is:

```
'BEAM_ME_UP_SGO_TY____N__INTU_LYGENT__IFE' //Underscores represent space.
```

Using Libraries:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
```

Algorithm function:

```
/* Function reads one char at a time, and converts chars to int.
 * Resulting integer value then indexes into char array of 27 chars
 * A-Z and 'space', storing results in string stream.
 * */

void bitWiseOpsDemo(unsigned char *bytey, size_t sizeOfArray){ //Input char array and size.
    assert(sizeOfArray>0);
    const int READIBLE_AMOUNT = 5;
    int result;
    stringstream stringOfCharacters;
    string words;
    int numBitsReadible = 0;
    int shift;
    int indexInto;
    short buffer; //will be used to hold bits
    int whileLoopIndex = 0;

    while(whileLoopIndex<sizeOfArray) {
        (buffer |= (bytey[whileLoopIndex]) & 0xFF);
        numBitsReadible += 8;
        result |= (buffer & 0xFFFF); //copy buffer to result.
        while(numBitsReadible>=READIBLE_AMOUNT){//While readible, read
            result |= (buffer & 0xFFFF); //copy buffer to result.
            indexInto = result;
            result <<=5;
            numBitsReadible -= 5; //Reducd the amount of bytes readible by 5.

            //calculate the amount to shift result by
            shift = numBitsReadible;
            result <<= shift;
            indexInto >>=shift;

            (indexInto &= 0x1F); //set all bits to 0, except the five we want in mask
            stringOfCharacters << symbols[indexInto]; //Get symbol and store in streamstring
            if(numBitsReadible==0){
                (result &= 0x0000); //Flush buffer if none readible.
            }
        }
        buffer |= (result &= 0xFF00); // Change 'Y', not 'x': YYYYYYYY xxxxxxxx
        buffer <<= 8; //Make room in buffer for next char
        ++whileLoopIndex;
    }
    words = stringOfCharacters.str();
    cout << words << endl;
}
```

Comment: @NonCreature0714: What is the decompression algorithm?  What's the sample input?

Comment: @MooingDuck thanks for the question. The sample input is the first char array displayed in the question: `unsigned char bytes[25] = {9,0,207,176,159,163,255,33,58,115,199,255,255,181,223,67,102,69,173,6,35,103,245,160,164 };`

Comment: Right off the bat you're using `|=` on an uninitialized variable, which is problematic.

Comment: Also, `buffer & 0xFFFF` doesn't do anything.

Comment: 0xffff appears to be a 16 bit mask, or perhaps the bottom half of a 32 bit mask.  buffer and result are declared as int.  Do you know the size of int on your machine?  (on my machine/compiler, an int is 32 bits).  Consider using uintxx_t for all 3 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is not doing what you think it's doing, I commented it out...

```
result |= (buffer & 0xFFFF); //copy buffer to result.
```

It's not copying it. This is working code, note I've also changed the types used in bit manipulations to be unsigned in the following. The code produces

```
BEAMMEUPSCOTTYNOINTELLIGENTLIFE
```

which I believe is what you're trying to get. Code as follows, note, I think the C++ gurus on SO could make this look a lot neater.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
const int READIBLE_AMOUNT = 5;

const char symbols[27] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
  'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
  'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' '};

inline void bitWiseOpsDemo(unsigned char *bytey, size_t sizeOfArray){
  assert(sizeOfArray == 25);
  //const int READIBLE_AMOUNT = 5;
  unsigned int result = 0;
  stringstream stringOfCharacters;
  string words;
  int numBitsReadible = 0;
  int shift;
  unsigned int indexInto;
  unsigned short buffer = 0; //will be used to hold bits
  //sizeOfArray = 1; //Only want to loop once right now for testing purposes. Comment out later.
  int whileLoopIndex = 0;
  //int innerLoopIndex = 0;
  while(whileLoopIndex < sizeOfArray) {
    (buffer |= (bytey[whileLoopIndex]) & 0xFF);
    numBitsReadible += 8;
    //result |= (buffer & 0xFFFF); //copy buffer to result.
    result = buffer;
    while(numBitsReadible>=READIBLE_AMOUNT){//While readible, read
      result |= (buffer & 0xFFFF); //copy buffer to result.
      indexInto = result;
      result <<=5;
      //Only want to manipulate the 'result' here
      numBitsReadible -= 5; //Reducd the amount of bytes readible by 5.
      //calculate the amount to shift result by
      shift = numBitsReadible;
      result <<= shift;
      indexInto >>=shift;
      //set all bits to 0, except the five we want in mask
      (indexInto &= 0x1F);

      stringOfCharacters << symbols[indexInto]; //Get symbol and store in streamstring
      if(numBitsReadible==0) {
        (result &= 0x0000); //Flush buffer if none readible.
      }   
    }   
    buffer |= (result &= 0xFF00); // Change 'Y', not 'x': YYYYYYYY xxxxxxxx
    buffer <<= 8; //Make room in buffer for next char
    ++whileLoopIndex;
  }
  words = stringOfCharacters.str();
  cout << words << endl;
}


const size_t SIZE = 25; 

int main() {
  unsigned char bytes[SIZE] = {9, 0, 207, 176, 159, 163, 255, 33, 58, 115, 199, 255, 255, 181, 223, 67, 102, 69, 173, 6, 35, 103, 245, 160, 164};
  bitWiseOpsDemo(bytes, SIZE);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given two great answers, I selected Harry's as the answer because he clearly indicated to my mistakes and provided straightforward guidance. By indicating the critical flaws I needed to receive education on, I've taken a little step forward.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to treat the code extraction as an iterator (in this case a forward_only iterator for simplicity).

This allows you to employ std algorithms for the logic while leaving the iterator to extract chunks of 5 bits.

Here's a (simple) example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template<std::size_t Bits>
struct bit_iterator
{
    bit_iterator(const unsigned char* buffer, std::size_t bitnum)
    : _buffer(buffer)
    , _bitnum(bitnum)
    {}

    std::size_t operator*() {
        std::size_t result = 0;
        for(std::size_t count = 0 ; count < Bits ; ++count)
        {
            auto bit = 7 - (_bitnum % 8);
            auto byte = _bitnum / 8;
            auto val = _buffer[byte] & (1 << bit);
            if (val) {
                result |= 1 << ((Bits-1) - count);
            }
            ++_bitnum;
        }
        return result;
    }

    bit_iterator<Bits>& operator++() {
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const bit_iterator<Bits>& r) const {
        return _buffer == r._buffer && (_bitnum + Bits) > r._bitnum;
    }

    bool operator!=(const bit_iterator<Bits>& r) const {
        return !(*this == r);
    }

    const unsigned char* _buffer;
    std::size_t _bitnum;
};

struct to_char
{

    char operator()(std::size_t index) const {
        return symbols[index];
    }
    static const char symbols[27];
};

const char to_char::symbols[27] = {
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
    'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
    'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' '
};

int main()
{
    static const unsigned char bytes[25] = { 9,0,207,176,159,163,255,33,58,115,
        199,255,255,181,223,67,102,69,173,
        6,35,103,245,160,164 };


    // stream to stdout

    std::transform(bit_iterator<5>(bytes, 0),
                   bit_iterator<5>(bytes, std::extent<decltype(bytes)>::value * 8),
                   std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout),
                   to_char());
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // or to a string
    std::string result;
    std::transform(bit_iterator<5>(bytes, 0),
                   bit_iterator<5>(bytes, std::extent<decltype(bytes)>::value * 8),
                   std::back_inserter(result),
                   to_char());
    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    // or just print the codes
    std::copy(bit_iterator<5>(bytes, 0),
              bit_iterator<5>(bytes, std::extent<decltype(bytes)>::value * 8),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::size_t>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
BEAM?ME?UP?SCOTTY????NO?INTELLIGENT?LIFE
BEAM?ME?UP?SCOTTY????NO?INTELLIGENT?LIFE
1, 4, 0, 12, 31, 12, 4, 31, 20, 15, 31, 18, 2, 14, 19, 19, 24, 31, 31, 31, 31, 13, 14, 31, 8, 13, 19, 4, 11, 11, 8, 6, 4, 13, 19, 31, 11, 8, 5, 4,
```

Printing out the codes may help to diagnose the encoding problem.

Comment: This answer is excellent, and a great example of good generic programming, and demonstrates great use of the STL and knowledge of it. This is certainly the way I will be approaching bitwise obstacles in the future. Unfortunately I can't select it as the answer because it gave me an entirely new – *and better* – way to solve my problem, rather than indicate my particular mistakes. Thank you for your contribution to my personal knowledge and to stack overflow on the whole.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 You are absolutely welcome. Learning the stl is probably the single most important step for any c++ programmer. Why build scaffolding when we can stand on the shoulders of giants?